# Jquery masks and validation do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

So if 'newseasons' works just fine but 'oldseasons' won't let me put 8 signs so 1.0.0.10 it expects 9 even though i set minlength to 8 and maxlength to 9 and also warnings about length do not show up but they work fine with oldseasons part. It seems like switching between those two doesn't update messages and restrictions in jquery validation.

```
 echo '<form id="first_form" action="#" method="POST" style="border: 0; margin: 0;">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$formid.'" name="formid">';
                    echo '<h1>Season, Patch version & amount of champions</h1>';
                    echo '<select id="season" onchange="checkseason();">';
                        echo '<option value="newseasons" selected>Season 3+</option>';
                        echo '<option value="oldseasons">Season 1, 2</option>';
                    echo '</select>';
                    echo '<input id="patch" type="text" name="patch" placeholder="e.g. 4.20" required autofocus><br/>';
                    echo '<input placeholder="Number of Champions" value="1" type="number" name="champ_number" min="1" max="20" required><br/>';
                    echo '<input type="submit" value="next">';
                echo '</form>';


        $.mask.definitions['~'] = "[+-]";
        $.mask.definitions['x'] = '[0-9]';
        $.mask.definitions['*'] = '[-A-Za-z0-9._\\\/?&=~]';


        function checkseason(){
            d = document.getElementById("season").value;
                if(d==='newseasons'){
                    $('#first_form').validate({
                        rules: {
                            patch: {
                                required: true,
                                minlength: 4,
                                remote: {
                                    url: "../checkpatch.php",
                                    type: "post"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        messages: {
                            patch: {
                                required: "Please enter patch version.",
                                remote: "Patch with this number already exists.",
                                minlength: "Please enter 3 numbers"
                                }
                            },

                    });


                $("#patch").mask("x.xx", {
                    placeholder: ""
                });

            }
            else if(d==='oldseasons'){
                $('#first_form').validate({
                        rules: {
                            patch: {
                                required: true,
                                minlength: 8,
                                maxlength: 9,
                                remote: {
                                    url: "../checkpatch.php",
                                    type: "post"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        messages: {
                            patch: {
                                required: "Please enter patch version.",
                                remote: "Patch with this number already exists.",
                                minlength: "Please enter 8 numbers"
                                }
                            },

                    });


                $("#patch").mask("x.x.x.xxx", {
                    placeholder: ""
                });


            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){

            checkseason();

        });
```

UPDATE still does not work but i think that is the right way to go from other posts that I've read on stack

```
function checkseason(){
                                d = document.getElementById("season").value;

                                                $('#first_form').validate({
                                                        rules: {
                                                                patch: {
                                                                        required: true
                                                                        remote: {
                                                                                url: "../checkpatch.php",
                                                                                type: "post"
                                                                                }
                                                                        }
                                                                },
                                                        messages: {
                                                                patch: {
                                                                        required: "Please enter patch version.",
                                                                        remote: "Patch with this number already exists.",
                                                                        minlength: "Please enter 3 numbers"
                                                                        }
                                                                },

                                                });

                                        if(d==='newseasons'){
                                                $('#first_form').rules('add', {
                                                        minlength: 4
                                                });

                                                $("#patch").mask("x.xx", {
                                                        placeholder: ""
                                                });
                                        }

                                        else if(d==='oldseasons'){
                                                $('#first_form').rules('add', {
                                                        minlength: 8,
                                                        maxlength: 9
                                                });

                                                $("#patch").mask("x.x.x.xxx", {
                                                        placeholder: ""
                                                });
                                        }


                        }
```

Comment: I see one issue immediately.  It appears as if you don't realize that calling `.validate()` is merely initializing the plugin on your form.  You'd never call it conditionally from within an `onchange` handler... it just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Any simple way to fix this?

Comment: [There are a few posts here from people who have attempted to combine jQuery Validate with masking](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+mask).  However, I never understood why you'd want to do this as they are two totally separate approaches for the same thing.  "Masking" ensures data follow a certain format by only allowing entry in that format.  "Validation" ensures data follow a certain format by giving the user an error message and blocking submission of the data.  Just my opinion, do one or the other.

Comment: Well the code does not work even without the mask part

Comment: Yes, see [my very first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013937/jquery-masks-and-validation-do-not-work?noredirect=1#comment50057046_31013937) above.  Perhaps also review [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org) and [wiki tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for basic setup and usage.